# obtener JSON creado por API con JQUERY

Tags: jquery, api

Estoy tratandod e consumir un API a traves de Jquery, al momento he logrado conectarme sin problema e incluso obtengo la respuesta del API el cual tiene el siguiente formato:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "status_codes": [
    200
  ],
  "status_messages": [
    {
      "request": "Request processed."
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "package": {
      "contentValue": 120.01,
      "weight": 1.01,
      "length": 30.01,
      "height": 15.01
    },
    "insurance": {
      "contentValue": 120.01,
      "amountInsurance": 2.09
    },
    "originZipCode": "44100",
    "destinationZipCode": "44510",
    "rates": [
      {
        "idRates": 999999,
        "idProduct": 11,
        "product": "Dos días",
        "vehicle": "bike",
        "idCarrier": 6,
        "carrier": "ESTAFETA",
        "total": 203.15,
        "deliveryType": "Ocurre",
        "deliveryDays": 1
      }
    ],
    "idCarriersNoWsResult": "44510"
  }
}
```

Esta información la puedo ver en la consola mediante console.log, pero no he podido plasmarla en un div, el código que uso es:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {'Authorization':'Mi Clave de Usuario o API KEY', 'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    url: 'https://api.envioclickpro.com/api/v1/quotation',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: packInfo,
    success: function(respuesta){
        console.log(respuesta);
    }
})
```

Como puedo almacenar ese JSON en un array ya sea de php o JS para poder acceder a su información?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nat, parece que debes aprender como imprimir cosas en el dom y mas allá de ello empezar a trabajar con tecnología y APIs mas modernas, aunque en teoría está bien, en la practica es mejor actualizarse, por eso te dejo [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) que es mas moderno y es estandar para manejar peticiones, puede que hasta mas intuitivo, por otro lado estaría bien que trabajaras con JS Vanilla aunque en principio aún ne he visto donde has utilizado Jquey.

A continuación te dejo un ejemplo de como imprimir Json en el dom:

```js
var preformato = document.querySelector("#main");
fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/hinqa")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => main.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res,null,2))
```

```html
<pre id="main"></pre>
```

Como ves obteniendo un Json de cualquier fuente podemos imprimirlo en nuestro documento dentro de una etiqueta pre y formateandolo con `JSON.stringify(json,null,2)` el dos del tercer parámetro indica la cantidad del tabulado.

Si quieres hacerlo con Jquery seria tan sencillo como:

```
$("#main").html(JSON.stringify(res,null,2))
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: Me ha funcionado perfectamente la sentencia de Jquery me comentabas. Respecto a fetch necesito leer la documentación ya que era una función que no conocía. GRacias.

Answer (score 1):

Ahí mismo, en tu función success, donde haces la lectura de consola la puedes asiganar tu respuesta a un arreglo.

```
var lstRespuesta = [];
$.ajax({
    headers: {'Authorization':'Mi Clave de Usuario o API KEY', 'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    url: 'https://api.envioclickpro.com/api/v1/quotation',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: packInfo,
    success: function(respuesta){
        console.log(respuesta);
        lstRespuesta.push(respuesta);
    }
})
```

Después le puedes dar uso para cargar tu data en el div a como lo necesites.

```
let data = lstRespuesta[0].data;
$("div#idTuDiv").html(data.idCarriersNoWsResult);
```